# CodeChef PRIME1 problem in Python

Tags: python, programming-challenge, primes, time-limit-exceeded

[PRIME1 is a CodeChef problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/PRIME1) which states:

> Shridhar wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem.
>   Help him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given
>   numbers.
>
> #### Input
>
> The first line contains t, the number of test cases (less then or
>   equal to 10). Followed by t lines which contain two numbers m and n (1
>   <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.
>
> #### Output
>
> For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n,
>   one number per line. Separate the answers for each test case by an
>   empty line.

I have used segmented sieve and my code doesn't give TLE on any CodeChef IDE etc. yet I am getting a TLE. How can I optimise this code?

```
import math
max_n=10**9
m = int(math.sqrt(max_n))
arr = [1]*m
arr[0] = arr[1] = 0 
#Calculate primes upto math.sqrt(max_n)
for x in xrange(m):
    for i in xrange(2,int(x**0.5)+1):
        if x%i==0:
            arr[x]=0
            break
list_prime=[]
for i,each in enumerate(arr):
    if each==1:
        list_prime.append(i)

#sieve b/w m and n
for _ in xrange(int(raw_input().strip())):
    m,n = map(int,raw_input().split())
    arr = range(m,n+1) if m>1 else range(2,n+1)
    for each in list_prime:
        firstfactor = (arr[0]/each)*each
        for x in xrange(firstfactor,n+1,each):
            try:
                if x!=each:
                    arr.remove(x)
            except:
                pass
    for each in arr:
        print each
    print
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Using the same variables for different purposes in the same block of code is confusing to the reader. Split the code in 2-3 functions so that they become local variables.
- You use trial division to compute the list of small primes even though you know about sieving. Sieving is faster.
- `arr.remove(x)` in the innermost loop is slow because it scans through the whole list (to find the element to remove, and to move subsequent elements back). Use a set instead, or a list of boolean values similar to `arr` in the first part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an efficient implementation of segmented sieve.

First, you are finding the prime numbers up to sqrt(nmax) by trial division. You should use the sieve of Eratosthenes instead.

```
for x in xrange(m):
    if arr[x]==0:
        continue
    for i in xrange(x*x,m+1,x):
        arr[i]=0
```

You can now use a similar Boolean array for the segmented sieve as well.

```
arr = [1] * (n-m+1)
for each in list_prime:
    firstfactor = max((m-1)/each+1,2)*each
    for x in xrange(firstfactor,n+1,each):
        arr[x-m]=0
```

Just output the nonzero elements in arr and you are done.

Comment: I think it will be 'continue' instead of 'break' in the upper code. Further, the second code will not generate all prime nos if (m,n) overlaps with (1,sqrt(10^9)) for eg. firstfactor for 2 will be 2 itself if (m,n) is (2,x). Hence arr[2-2]=0 and 2 will not be considered a prime.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, is it fixed now?

Comment: No, it's not fixed completely yet. The upper code too is bugged. Think about how many times the outer loop will run.

Comment: The overall complexity will be m log log m where m = sqrt(nmax), I don't see the problem.

Comment: It can be optimised because it needs to run only sqrt(m) times. Plus there are multiple bugs in your lower code. Now that I have solved the problem, I can see.