# Optimised Python Code gives TLE for PRIME1

Tags: python, programming-challenge, primes, time-limit-exceeded

[PRIME1 is a codechef problem which states:](https://www.codechef.com/problems/PRIME1)

> Shridhar wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem.
>   Help him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given
>   numbers.
>
> Input
>
> The first line contains t, the number of test cases (less then or
>   equal to 10). Followed by t lines which contain two numbers m and n (1
>   <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.
>
> Output
>
> For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n,
>   one number per line. Separate the answers for each test case by an
>   empty line.

I have optimised my code according to suggestions given [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159857/codechef-prime1-problem-in-python?noredirect=1#comment302969_159857). But, my edits were rolled back when I tried to post my optimised code. So, I am still getting a TLE error and I don't understand why. Help me optimise this code further:

```
import math
def sieve_basic_list(list_prime):
    max_n=10**9
    m = int(math.sqrt(max_n))
    lim = int(math.sqrt(m))+1
    arr = [True]*(m+1)
    arr[0]=arr[1]=False

    #Calculate primes upto m only so loop runs sqrt(m) times.
    for x in xrange(2,lim):
        if arr[x]==False:
            continue
        for i in xrange(x*x,m+1,x):
            arr[i]=False
    for i,each in enumerate(arr):
        if each:
            list_prime.append(i)

def mnsieve(list_prime):
    #program tc input and mnrange calc
    for _ in xrange(int(raw_input().strip())):
        m,n = map(int,raw_input().split())
        mnrange = [True]*(n-m+1)
        mnrange[0] = False if m==1 else True
        for each in list_prime:
            firstfactor = ((m-1)/each)*each #firstfactor nearest to m i.e firstfactor-m gives index
            for x in xrange(firstfactor,n+1,each):
                try:
                    if x not in list_prime:
                        mnrange[x-m]=False
                except:
                    pass
        for i,each in enumerate(mnrange):
            if each:
                print i+m
        print

list_prime=[]
sieve_basic_list(list_prime)
mnsieve(list_prime)
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to re-read Janne Karila's third point, as you changed it to something as bad.

Comment: If you want to keep this approach, at least change `list_prime=[]` to `list_prime=set([])` and `list_prime.append(i)` to `list_prime.add(i)`. That alone will give you quite the speed improvement. I'd consider re-writing it, though.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Why so? I'm no longer removing an element by searching and then shifting the rest because I don't use remove() anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. And [these](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159857/codechef-prime1-problem-in-python?noredirect=1#comment302969_159857) suggestions helped. Here is the final solution:

```
import math
def sieve_basic_list(list_prime):
    max_n=10**9
    m = int(math.sqrt(max_n))
    lim = int(math.sqrt(m))+1
    arr = [True]*(m+1)
    arr[0]=arr[1]=False

    #Calculate primes upto m only so loop runs sqrt(m) times.
    for x in xrange(2,lim):
        if arr[x]==False:
            continue
        for i in xrange(x*x,m+1,x):
            arr[i]=False
    for i,each in enumerate(arr):
        if each:
            list_prime.add(i)

def mnsieve(list_prime):
    #program tc input and mnrange calc
    for _ in xrange(int(raw_input().strip())):
        m,n = map(int,raw_input().split())
        mnrange = [True]*(n-m+1)
        mnrange[0] = False if m==1 else True
        for each in list_prime:
            if each <= int(n**0.5): #important optmisation
                firstfactor = ((m-1)/each)*each #firstfactor nearest to m i.e firstfactor-m gives index
                for x in xrange(firstfactor,n+1,each):
                        if x!=each and x-m >= 0: #x-m can become -ve and that is disastorous in python lists!
                            mnrange[x-m]=False
       for i,each in enumerate(mnrange):
            if each:
                print i+m
       print

list_prime=set([]) #important optimisation
sieve_basic_list(list_prime)
mnsieve(list_prime)
```

Check it here: [on codechef](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/13212030)